# Handle of my faucet is calcined

Tags: bathroom, repair, faucet

My faucet is becoming way calcined and it is getting sticky when I try to rotate it in order to open the water.

[image: Calcined faucet]

How should I proceed in order to make it less sticky as when I bought them?

Comment: I use a product called CLR (calcium, Lime & rust remover) I have had good success using this product on fixtures applying several times with a rag saturated in CLR.  If you can get that product give it a try. White vinegar may also help but will take many applications. 
I have no connection to the CLR company just like this product.

Comment: Be sure you can get internal parts still for it - some of these old ones are impossible to get grommets and washers for.

Comment: Vinegar and an old toothbrush.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The photo appears to be of a very old, possibly nickel-plated brass fixture with the plating worn off and a significant copper-based corrosion process ongoing.

I doubt that you'll find any quick fix here as you'll either need to replace it entirely or completely disassemble it, remove all corrosion from it, re-plate it as appropriate, and replace all of its worn parts before it will work as new again.

I'm sure you can find some articles online about this process. Cleaning off the corrosion is likely to be easy enough. I'd start with a product such as CLR or similar that is sold where you live. That, plus some steel wool, should yield a cleaned-up surface. Plating takes special equipment and while it can be done yourself, if you want nice results you should find a local shop that does this.

Comment: You can use simple household vinegar to clean it which is considerably less toxic than CLR (other than the toxity CLR is amazing). However to use vinegar you will need to remove the faucet and soak it in the vinegar to get good effect.

Answer (score 4):

Does "sticky" mean it is hard to turn? If so ,pretty easy fix ; remove the handle, unthread the packing nut/collar on the stem, replace packing or make your own by putting several wraps of teflon tape-pipe dope on the stem , reassemble. Adjust the collar/nut tightness to seal and give the amount of turn resistance you want.( This is all done with the water off). The white calcium water deposit should come off with vinegar. The metal may be German silver ( brass with enough nickel to color it silver) which should polish up well.

Comment: Thank you @blacksmith37. Yes, I meant that.

Comment: Vinegar works well, and so does CLR and Lime-a-way. I've used these three, separately (don't mix cleaners), and know they all work. Some toilet cleaners also work well, as they have muriatic acid in them, but that can react with some tubs, like fiberglass, so be careful. Always read the label and make sure you are aware of possible reactions, and wear Personal Protective Equipment (PPE), as even vinegar can be dangerous in the right concentrations.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is limescale that has built up over the years, then vinegar is the miracle solvent that will dissolve it for you. Any weak acid will do, but vinegar is cheap is readily available.

You can either put it on a sponge and scrub or else apply it to tissue paper and leave for a few hours or overnight. You could even put some in your kettle and boil the vinegar first, which apart from descaling your kettle will make the vinegar dissolve things faster.

Distilled (clear) vinegar will do the trick and is about 5% acidity, its even cheaper if you buy a 5l bottle for household use, though you might also be able to find extra-stong pickling/cleaning vinegar upto 20% acidity.